# SET_RCVTIMEO understanding

Tags: unix, gstreamer, rtmp

Can anybody explain me the usage of SET_RCVTIMEO. And what is the difference between SET_RCVTIMEO and SO_RCVTIMEO. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for this. SO_RCVTIMEO is used to set the receive socket timeout in linux. This can be achieved using "setsockopt" API in linux. Similarly you have SO_SNDTIMEO to set the send socket timeout in linux. This can be achieved using "getsockopt" API in linux.

More details:
(http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html)